# How to terminate Grails 2.3 application started with "run-app"?

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

Prior to version 2.3 a Grails application started in a console window with "**run-app**" (development mode) could be terminated with **Ctrl-C**. It doesn't work anymore with Grails 2.3, the keystroke is simply ignored. There's "**stop-app**" command, but it doesn't terminate the running application either.

I can terminate the app by killing the console window, but I prefer not to do so, because in this case I'm loosing all debugging output that was printed to that console.

Comment: What issue/error do you face with stop-app?

Comment: What environment are you on? Ctrl-C works for me on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Java 1.7.0_45, Grails 2.3.4.
After the application starts pressing Ctrl-C has no effect. The app doesn't terminate. No errors thrown. It's just keeps running.

Comment: That sometimes happens to me on Ubuntu 13.04 if there's been an earlier OutOfMemoryError, otherwise ctrl-c normally works

Comment: I've always used the trick of creating an empty file called `.kill-run-app` in the application's base directory, does that still work in 2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was fixed by upgrading from Grails **2.3.4** to **2.3.7**. In Grails 2.3.7 **Ctrl-C**, "**run-app**" and "**stop-app**" behave as documented. I consider this case closed.

*(I'm not sure if this qualifies as the answer, but I feel that the question deserves some form of a closure...)*

Answer (score 1):

From http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode
"Since Grails 2.3, the run-app, run-war, test-app and console commands are now executed in a forked JVM in order to isolate the build classpath from the runtime classpath."

You'll notice that two java.exe processes are created if you use these default settings, and CTRL-C only kills one of them.

I noticed this myself.  Just comment out the following line in your BuildConfig.groovy

`run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256],`

Comment: Thank you, Jamie, for suggestion, but it didn't work for me. I started by app with the "run: [...]" line commended out (as you suggested), as well as the entire "grails.project.fork = [...]" closure, but still, neither Ctrl-C, nor "stop-app" stop the running application. Did that work for you?

Comment: That's odd.  If I uncomment the fork section, two java.exe processes are created, but when commented out, it only creates one (which I re-verified before I posted).  Does CTRL-C stop one of the two processes (I'm assuming there are two in your case).

Comment: Jamie, you'right that the line "run: [...]" controls whether the app is run by the main java process or a forked one (one or two java.exe processes). My problem is that in neither case the application is terminated by Ctrl-C or "grails stop-app" command.